# ZEROFILL column always starts with 000 not 0001

Tags: mysql

I Use `ZEROFILL` attribute of the column in MySQL.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE `columnName` `columnName` INT(3) ZEROFILL;
```

The problem is the first record is always **inserted as 000 not 001**, is there a solution.

[image]

Comment: are you altering existing records?

Comment: @Rogue no I am inserting a new record.the column is autonumber

Comment: But you posted an `ALTER TABLE` statement, what's your insert statement? It'd be easier to also just post your table definition instead of some arbitrary alter statement. We can't see if that column is auto-increment, we're not oracles.

Comment: It just fills with zeroes, it doesn't add a value, like the name suggests. When you have a value of `1` in your column it will become `001`, when you have `10` it will become `010`. When you don't store a value in there, it will become `000` of course. Did you expect it to be an auto_increment column?

Comment: You might want to add AUTO_INCREMENT to your column def.

Comment: @Rogue insert statement does not insert the warehouseID, if you read what I said it is autonumber so there is no question of adding the insert statement here

Comment: When you alter the column, you have to repeat `auto_increment` there as well, or it will no longer apply.

Comment: @trincot When I tried to autoincrement it throws an error http://prntscr.com/gbj6ld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you have defined the column with `auto_increment` in the original `create table` statement, you need to repeat that option again when doing an `alter table` on that particular column. If you omit it there, MySql will actually drop that `auto_increment` option from the column.

So do:

```
alter table warehouse change warehouseID
    warehouseID int(3) zerofill auto_increment;
```